# How can I find a generalized expresion for $A^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to find a generalized expresion for $A^{n}$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 3\\ 
-6 & 7
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

Do you have any idea of how can I do that?

Comment: diagonalize: $A=SD S^{-1}$

Comment: wolfram's answer not looking to great: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-5%2C+3%7D%2C%7B-6%2C7%7D%7D%5En

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{bmatrix} -5 & 3\\ -6 & 7 \end{bmatrix},~~ B=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ Let $A=I+3B$
Here, $$B^2=2I, B^3=2B, B^4=2^2I,B^5=2^2 B......$$, then

$$A^n=(I+3 B)^n=I+ {n \choose 1}3 B+{n \choose 2} 3^2 B^2+ {n \choose 3} 3^3 B^3+....+{b \choose n}3^nB^n$$
$$A^n=I\sum_{k=0}^{n} (3\sqrt{2})^{2k} {n \choose 2k} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (3 \sqrt{2})^{2k+1} {n \choose 2k+1}=P_n I+ Q_n B.$$
The elements of $A^n$ turn out to be  integers.

$$A^n= \begin{bmatrix} P_n & 0 \\ 0 & P_n \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} -2Q_n & Q_n \\ -2Q_n &  2Q_n \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} P_n -2Q_n & Q_n \\ -2Q_n &  P_n+2Q_n \end{bmatrix}$$
Where $$P_n=\frac{1}{2}[(1+3\sqrt{2})^n+ (1-3\sqrt{2})^n],$$
$$Q_n=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1+3\sqrt{2})^n - (1-3\sqrt{2})^n].$$

Comment: @Z Ahmed:very nice idea! +1

Answer (score 2):

Write in form of jordan
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
-5-\lambda & 3 \\
-6 & 7-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|=0\\\lambda_1=-3\sqrt2+1\\\lambda_2=3\sqrt2+1$$solve it for eigen vectors
$$(\left(\begin{matrix}
-5 & 3 \\
-6 & 7
\end{matrix}\right)-(-3\sqrt2+1)I)X=\bar{0}\to V_1=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$$,
$$(\left(\begin{matrix}
-5 & 3 \\
-6 & 7
\end{matrix}\right)-(3\sqrt2+1)I)X=\bar{0}\to V_2=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{2}+2}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$$,
$$M=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+2}{2} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
and wite it as
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-5 & 3 \\
-6 & 7
\end{matrix}\right)=\\
\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+2}{2} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
-3\sqrt{2}+1 & 0 \\
0 & 3\sqrt{2}+1
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+1}{2} \\
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)\\A=MDM^{-1}$$so
$$A^2=MDM^{-1}MDM^{-1}=MD^2M^{-1}\\A^3=MD^2M^{-1}MDM^{-1}=MD^3M^{-1}\\...\\A^N=MD^NM^{-1}$$